# Finding unknown in modulo operation

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have  this question on a test

1) find d=gcd(77,50) using euclidean alg.

2)find s and t such that 77s+50t=d

3) use these results to find x such that 50x=4(mod77) Note:the qual sign should have 3 lines

For the first part i found d=1 no problem there, for 2nd part at took me some twinking but i found s=13 and t=-20. my question is first is there a shortcut to doing 2nd part fast without trying to plug in random numbers and two for the third part how do i find x using my previous results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general answer to your second part is that you use the [Extended Euclidian Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) instead of the simple EA. From your result $s=13$ and $t=-20$ you know that the multipication modular inverse of 50 exist
$$50\times (-20) + 77\times 13 = 1 \quad \Longrightarrow
50\times (-20) \equiv  50\times 57 \equiv 1 \pmod {77}$$
and is $57 \pmod {77}$. To solve the the third part you simply multiply with this inverse
$$50x \equiv 4 \pmod {77}$$
$$\Longrightarrow 50^{-1}\times50 x\equiv 50^{-1}\times 4 \pmod {77}$$
$$\Longrightarrow x \equiv 50^{-1}\times 4 \equiv 57\times 4  \equiv 228 \equiv 74 \pmod {77}.$$
And as a check you verify that
$$74\times 50 \equiv 3700 \equiv 4  \pmod {77}.$$

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about the second part, there isn't really a fast way to do this. There is an algorithm that will give you the answer, no guessing involved. As the other answer mentions, it's called the [extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). On Wikipedia, they give the "distilled" version, which is well-suited to running on a computer, but I seem to mess it up by hand every time I try. (Side note: A number theory course was one of the first times I wrote computer to do things that were relevant to me, and I would highly recommend doing this, if you're interested).

The idea is that you save your work from the standard Euclidean algorithm, and back-substitute like crazy. I'll show you the relevant, rewritten Euclidean algorithm, and some of the arithmetic for finding those coefficients.

\begin{align}
77 - 50 &=27 \\
50 - 27 &=23 \\
27 - 23 &= 4 \\
23 - 5 \cdot 4&= 3 \\
4 - 3 &= 1
\end{align}

It's definitely a lot of work, any way you slice it. We're going to climb up the list, so first, we'd replace the $3$ with $23-4\cdot5$, in our last equation:

$$
4 - (23 - 4\cdot 5) =1.
$$ Now, we have to replaced all instances of $4$ with $27 - 23$:

$$
27 - 23 - (23 - (27 - 23)\cdot 5) =6\cdot 27 -7 \cdot 23 = 1.
$$

We'd continue climbing up, next replacing the $23$, and so forth. Hopefully that's enough for you to get the gist of what we need to do. I can certainly provide the rest of the details, if you're interested. That's the idea behind finding those coefficients.